# Error in java swing application in Mac

Tags: java, macos

Hi I have created a swing application using java 1.5 and i created a distributable jar of that file. I can run the jar in windows OS and linux OS but when i run in Mac it gives me error. I checked I am using java 1.5 version.

I think the program asks for java 1.6 version.

How to resolve the problem.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar sahoo

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the swing components eg= JOptionPane is in java1.5 in linux and Windows but its in java 1.6 in Mac. So u have to install java 1.6. Java launches different features in different platform as a new release. So install java 1.6. It will solve ur problem.

Comment: Please... references?  JOptionPane's been in Swing (no matter the platform) since JDK 1.2 - and I certainly don't remember any Swing components existing in one JDK on one platform and not in another... why would Sun even certify a "whoops guys - sorry we only implemented half the components" JDK.

Comment: @Nate: I agree with you.  What's the point in the JRE if different platforms have different components for the same version?